# Как посмотреть параметры при запуске бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Представим, что ваш друг книул вам ссылку:

```
t.me/ССЫЛКАНАБОТА?start=1234567
```

Вы заходите на бота, и другу начисляется допустим 10 монет. Как с помощью pyTelegramBotAPI посмотреть значение start внутри ссылки, по которой перешли? Как сделать так, чтобы бот смог прочитать эти 1234567?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Ваш токен')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handler(message):
    ref = message.text.split(' ')[-1]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ref)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Но учтите что нужно еще добавить проверку на уникальность пользователей которые перешли по ссылке. Иначе можно заабузить себе монет)

Comment: Спасибо, работает!